# gcc - how to detect pointer-based memory access

Tags: c++, c, gcc, decompiling

I'm focusing on micropython, specifically the branch [dynamic-native-modules](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/tree/dynamic-native-modules).

This feature will, in the future, allow you to compile a C/C++ function into a native `.obj` and package it together with a `.py` interface for a huge speed boost.

Awesome! But the issue is that if you're using a RTOS, which [doesn't have virtual memory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16980), then any executing native code can access any part of the  address space including peripherals, the RTOS' state etc.

You don't want the user to be able to do something like this:

```
void user_func()
{
/* point to arbitrary memory, potentially the reset registers, flash erase . . . you get the point */
  int * a = (int*)0x1234;  
  *a = 0x10110000; // DESTROY!!!
}
```

Even the following should be disallowed:

```
void user_func()
{
  int a;
  (int*)(&a-1000) = 0x10010111;
}
```

**SOLUTIONS?**

- Create own version of `gcc` (for each binary format)
- Decompile `.obj` files and detect use of pointers (for each binary binary format)

**FEEDBACK TO COMMENTS**

I get that it may be impossible to stop a **malicious** user but that's not the #1 worry. We want to stop well-meaning but accidental code. If it's not possible to stop every, single case that's *ok*.

If we can prohibit/detect explicit pointer accesses and simply provide warnings regarding array use, that is still very valuable.

> **WARNING**: YOU'RE USING AN ARRAY! MAKE SURE YOU DON'T GO OUT-OF-BOUNDS

Comment: This is the mother of XY-problems.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was very clear what the original problem is.

Comment: C++ without pointers is no longer C++.

Comment: Using an array and running over the end will also run somewhere in the memory, also without explicit use of pointers. C/C++ without any memory access will help...

Comment: @Klaus an answer of "it's not possible" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: If the specific OBJ can do some stuff, even if you forbid this stuff from a specific language, a malicious user will find a way to craft such an OBJ by other means. It means that your system architecture is just flawed in respect to it's requirements.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Our average user is not going to **want** to break things. Even the array out of bounds access may be an acceptable risk give the speedups to be gained.

Comment: As others commented and voted up the comments, you can get a feeling of how realistic your solution is. If "someone" can access your hardware and setup new software or execute some other stuff and you have no protecting hardware and OS, you will not be able to make your device safe.

Comment: Anyway. You can't remove the use of pointers from C without defeating it's completeness. And of course you can't remove it from obj, because it looks like a regular memory access. You can think of some kind of static analysis tool to analyze the compiled program and warning about dangerous constructs. It won't be easy, though.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Without raw pointers it is modern C++

Comment: @EugeneSh. and that sounds like the answer I was looking for (honestly). I didn't know if this was even possible when I wrote the question.

Comment: If you think static analysis is the only viable method to detecting pointer- and array-based memory accesses, vote up **original comment of @EugeneSh.**: `Anyway. You can't remove the use of pointers from C without defeating it's completeness. And of course you can't remove it from obj, because it looks like a regular memory access. You can think of some kind of static analysis tool to analyze the compiled program and warning about dangerous constructs. It won't be easy, though.`

Comment: Maybe you should check out Valgrind then. (I'm not using it so I won't post it as an answer.)

Comment: You can also use dynamic testing like valgrind, you can use emulators and simulators with "simulated memory protection" in debug mode. You can run your code on the target with a "check and execute" mechanism, decreasing the speed by 10 or more... maybe some other ideas?

Comment: @Fozi thanks! That'll detect (at least) `write off the end of array`; I'll do some more reading.

Comment: @Klaus at the level of embedded, even **reading** a memory-mapped register may have side-effects (like clearing it).

Comment: Yes, and for all that situations you can use simulators, emulators, valgrind, software mmu ( check 6 execute ) and so on. So simply do it, if you really want to use C++... valgrind must be used on a different compilation of your code on another, non embedded target.  But it should be possible to find out of bounds problems and also manipulated pointers.

Comment: what's `check 6 execute`?

Comment: a minimal proxy application, which checks each single assembler instruction before "really" execute it. This is sometimes called software mmu. But it is an exotic solution...

Comment: @Klaus and it’d slow things down? I’d rather have something that builds, runs and checks it on the PC and then if passes, builds it for the target architecture.

Comment: @Klaus actually the sw mmu sounds interesting; are there any standard ones I can investigate?

Comment: If you want memory safety, C and C++ are wrong places to look for it.

Comment: @n.m. What other languages can run on a micro controller?

Comment: The C Standard allows for "fat pointers", i.e. pointers that also contain provenance information so that runtime checks can ensure they never go out of bounds. I heard someone tried to enable fat pointers in gcc once but there were problems (I guess, probably due to existing code that assumes non-fatness). Also there is AddressSanitizer

Comment: Ada comes to mind.

Comment: @n.m. Is it binary compatible with C? Does ADA require a runtime?

Comment: Never used it really, but it is designed for embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

Your best chance is a GCC plugin which looks at the frontend-generated [GENERIC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GENERIC.html) or [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) IRs and implements the policies you want. Depending on the policies and the source code you want to accept, this could be a lot of work and very difficult.

If you want a purely syntax-based or type-based approach (simply rejecting all pointer arithmetic), Clang with its ASTs is easier to work with than GCC.

Comment: What's `IRs`?  (more placeholder characters)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way of doing what you want - as long as you protect from honest mistakes, not deliberate attempts to break things.

First, you embrace C++ Core Guidelines and use support from the tools: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-tools

For your purposes, it will stop your code from using raw pointers and pointer arithmetic in non-library code. Period. Core guidelines do more than that, but this is what is related to your question.

Than, you do a simple grep on the code to make sure it is not using pointers blessed by Guidelines - this would be a case of more or less simple `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it is not reasonably possible.

You might consider changing the compilation (e.g. with a GCC plugin, like mentioned in [Florian Weimer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47189236/841108)) to check every access to arrays, but that makes the generated code significantly slower. Your native hardware is slow enough, you don't want to make it even more slow.

And Python is not exactly the right source language. Its dynamic typing would make its quite slow already.

Perhaps you might consider a statically typed language, like Ocaml (combined with a JIT or AOT compilation library like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), etc). The type system (and its inference) increase the safety (and the speed) of the generated code, and with lot of hard work (several years, probably worth a PhD
since you'll need do new research) you might improve the type inference to even infer the occurrences where the array index is never out-of-bounds (and an index boundary check is not even needed).

In most case, upgrading the hardware (to a Raspberry Pi style one, with an MMU, and probably the ability to have a real OS with some virtual memory) is probably the most pragmatic approach

PS. Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem). Most static source analysis cannot work reliably and well (be sound and complete, in technical terms).